# Show the convergence of the integral $F(t,x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp[i\tau t-(i\tau)^{1/2}x - (i\tau)^\theta] \,d\tau$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers, improper-integrals

The original problem is :

Let $\theta$ be a number such that $1/2<\theta<1$. Prove that

$$F(t,x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp[i\tau t-(i\tau)^{1/2}x - (i\tau)^\theta] \,d\tau$$

defines a $C^\infty$ function in $\mathbb R^2$ which is a solution of the homogeneous heat equation

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x ^2}\quad\text{ (in $\mathbb R^2$)}$$

I tried to simplify the integrand but got nothing. First of all, I wanted to show the integral converges, but I've no idea. Can anyone give me some ideas to start? Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, I've edited the question. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: Just to confirm, $(i\tau)^\alpha$ denotes the principal branch defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$, right?

Comment: I would just take the partial derivatives of $F$...not sure if that is what you are looking for

Comment: @Daniel Fischer,the branch of the fractional powers $z^ \alpha $ arre always chosen in the "natural way": they are the ones that are positive on the positive half of the real axis.

Comment: @TylerHG, well, I quite doubt one can directly take the derivative inside of the integral... One has to show that the integral is well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the powers $(i\tau)^\alpha$ use the principal branch, we have, for $\tau\neq 0$,

$$\begin{align}
(i\tau)^{\alpha} &= \left((i\operatorname{sign} \tau) \lvert \tau\rvert\right)^\alpha\\
&= \left(e^{\operatorname{sign}\tau\cdot \pi i/2}\lvert \tau\rvert\right)^\alpha\\
&= \exp \left(\operatorname{sign}\tau \frac{\pi i \alpha}{2}\right) \lvert \tau\rvert^\alpha,
\end{align}$$

and therefore

$$\operatorname{Re}\: (i\tau)^{\alpha} = \cos \left(\frac{\pi\alpha}{2}\right) \lvert \tau\rvert^\alpha.$$

Thus, since $\lvert e^z\rvert = e^{\operatorname{Re} z}$,

$$\left\lvert\exp \left[i\tau t - (i\tau)^{1/2} x - (i\tau)^\theta\right] \right\rvert = \exp \left[-x\sqrt{\lvert\tau\rvert}\cos\frac{\pi}{4}  - \lvert\tau\rvert^\theta\cos \frac{\pi\theta}{2}\right].$$

Since $\frac{1}{2} < \theta < 1$, we have $\cos \frac{\pi\theta}{2} > 0$, and $\lvert\tau\rvert^\theta$ grows faster than $\lvert\tau\rvert^{1/2}$, hence for $\lvert x\rvert < K$, the integrand is dominated by

$$\exp \left(K \sqrt{\frac{\lvert\tau\rvert}{2}} - c\cdot \lvert\tau\rvert^\theta\right) \leqslant C\exp \left(-\tilde{c}\lvert\tau\rvert^\theta\right)\tag{$\ast$}$$

for some positive constants $C,\tilde{c}$ and $c = \cos \frac{\pi\theta}{2}$. The function on the right hand side of $(\ast)$ is integrable, and remains so when multiplied with arbitrary positive powers of $\lvert\tau\rvert$, so the dominated convergence theorem shows that $F$ is smooth, and the partial derivatives are obtained by differentiating under the integral. Differentiating under the integral also yields the differential equation, since $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ brings a factor of $i\tau$ down from the exponent, and each $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ a factor of $(i\tau)^{1/2}$.

Comment: This is clear. You know what, I proved the case for $\tau>0$ by the same way as you posted, but got messed up if $\tau<0$. I got an equality: $\tau ^ \theta = exp(\frac{1}{\theta}log{\tau})=exp(\frac{1}{\theta}(log|\tau|+iArg{\tau})$ and later I took a huge detour because I had to handle the minus sign a lot. I think the smart part in your anser is to let $\tau=sign\tau$. Thanks!